# condition to be a norm on a finite dimensional complex vector space

Tags: normed-spaces

[image]

Here x is an element of C^n, where n is a natural number and C is the complex number field, and p is any positive number. This becomes a norm when p>=1. But, what happens when p is between 0 and 1? I know that the thing in the picture does not become a norm when p is between 0 and 1. However, I can't get an idea to prove it. Could anyone help me?

Comment: what do you mean by: "what happens when 0"?

Comment: Sorry there was an error. I corrected the question.

Comment: if it was a norm the closed ball with center $0$ and radius $1$ would be a convex set. I think you can prove it is not the case when $p<1$

Comment: Hint: The triangle inequality is violated. It won't be a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 2$ (and correspondingly for the complex space).

Comment: I tried to find an example where the triangle inequality fails. But, I can't find one myself..Could you suggest one?